# replace a pattern in file by another replacement string present in another file using PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, pattern-matching, wordnet

I've to find collocations of wordnet in my text file.Since collocations are more than one word or having special char like ' - . i've got the list of such strings/collocations stored .Now in my text file(from corpus) i need to identify if any of these strings occur.
Problem is since im using a POS tagger the multiword collocations are regarded as seperate words,so i need to first get a collocation from my collocation list,find if it occurs in the text and then replace the spaces in the collocation by some special character like _ so the pos tagger considers it as one.
i tried preg_replace on the text file contents for every collocation in my list but my browser either crashes or shows a memory overload error

```
$m=file_get_contents ('sample.txt');
$comp=file('collocation_list.txt');
for ($x=0; $x<= count($comp); $x++)
{
       $comp[$x] = trim(strtolower($comp[$x]));
   $c =$comp[$x];
   $rep=str_replace(" ","_",$c);
   $rep=" ".$rep." "; 
   $m =preg_replace($c,$rep,$m);   

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a word pattern search or something using the wordnet db?

Comment: Im not using db as for now,ive stored the collocation list in a text file,so for every collocation in that file i run a preg_replace function that finds the occurrences of the collocation in the sample text file(from the corpus) and then replaces it by a collocation which has _ wherevr a space occured

Comment: Because you're looking at a memory limitation, you probably need to indicate the size of the files you're dealing with. Even better, you could provide the actual files for us to work with.